# Sum of n numbers in a given interval

Tags: probability

Fix a natural number $n$. Suppose $x_i\in [0,1], 1\leq i\leq n$. What does the sum of $x_i $ most likely be?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer and the sum will be anywhere from $0$ to $n$.  If you were to specify that each $x_i$ was taken from the interval *uniformly at random* for example, or specify some other distribution that they will follow, then we could give more of a result.  In particular, if we know the expected value of each $x_i$ individually, we can use the linearity of expectation to show that $E[\sum x_i]=\sum E[x_i]$ which in the case of uniform distribution would mean the expected value of the sum would be $\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: If the $x$s are reals there is no number that is most likely.  You can ask about the expectation of the sum, which is $\frac n2$.  Please *think* about your question and improve it.  Voting to close as not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have left something out. If we don't know how these $x_i$ are distributed on the interval $[0,1]$, how on earth are we supposed to find what the sum is most likely to be?

I'm going to assume the question suggests that $x_i$ are chosen randomly and uniformly from the interval $[0,1]$. That is, each $x_i$ is a uniform$[0,1]$ random variable.

Then we just use simple linearity of expectation to get:

$E[\sum_1^n x_i] = \sum_1^n x_i = \sum_1^n \frac{1}{2} = \frac{n}{2}$

Where we use the fact that if $X \sim Uniform[a,b]$ then $E[X] = \frac{b-a}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you need to say how you're choosing the $x_i$; specifically, what's the probability distribution for each $x_i$ (and are the $x_i$ independent).